# Flutter canvas draw raw points with different colors

Tags: flutter, flutter-canvas, flutter-custompainter

I am trying to draw a lot of points to the screen quickly. I have created the following method.

```
void _paintPoints(Canvas canvas, List matrix, Size size) {
  final width = size.width / matrix.length;
  final height = size.height / matrix.first.length;
  Float32List points = Float32List(matrix.length * matrix.length * 2);
  final pointColors = <Color>[];

  for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
      final x = i * width;
      final y = j * height;
      final index = (i * matrix.length + j) * 2;

      points[index] = x;
      points[index + 1] = y;

      Color color = Color.fromARGB(
          matrix[i][j][3], matrix[i][j][0], matrix[i][j][1], matrix[i][j][2]);
      pointColors.add(color);
    }
  }

  canvas.drawRawPoints(
    PointMode.points,
    points,
    paint
      ..blendMode = BlendMode.srcOver
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0,
  );
}
```

This method is able to draw the points quickly but all of the points are the same color (The `pointColors` are not used). Is there away to use `drawRawPoints()` or some other `Canvas` method to draw a lot of points (tens of thousands) quickly with specific colors?

I have tried drawing each point separately, but it was too slow.

Comment: Have you tried grouping the points by same color and then running DrawRawPoints? Also, if there is gradient based color, you could use shader in paint.

Comment: @Rahul This was an improvement (about 5x faster). The issue with this solution is that I do not know how many times each colour appears before I check them. Because of this I cannot create Float32List. I am currently creating Map<Color, List<double>> and converting the list to Float32List before drawing. According to the performance tools the hashmap checking and adding items to the List<double> take more time than the painting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```dart
void _paintPoints(Canvas canvas, List matrix, Size size) {
  final width = size.width / matrix.length;
  final height = size.height / matrix.first.length;

  final Map<Color, Set<Offset>> map = HashMap();

  for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
      final offset = Offset(i * width, j * height);
      final color = Color.fromARGB(
          matrix[i][j][3], matrix[i][j][0], matrix[i][j][1], matrix[i][j][2]);
      map.putIfAbsent(color, () => HashSet()).add(offset);
    }
  }

  for (var e in map.entries) {
    canvas.drawRawPoints(
      PointMode.points,
      Float32List.fromList(e.value.expand((e) => [e.dx, e.dy]).toList()),
      paint
        ..color = e.key
        ..blendMode = BlendMode.srcOver
        ..strokeWidth = 2.0,
    );
  }
}
```

I am sorry I had to post it as answer. It is a try out code. I would suggest to cache the map result and use diff of upcoming matrix and size to calculate new map values.

Edit:
I did some editing and it should run fast. The idea here is to minimize memaddr calculation.

Updated code

```dart
void _paintPoints(Canvas canvas, List matrix, Size size) {
  final r = matrix.length;
  final c = matrix.first.length;
  final width = size.width / r;
  final height = size.height / c;

  final Map<Color, Set<Offset>> map = HashMap();

  for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    final row = matrix[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < c; j++) {
      final cell = row[j];
      final offset = Offset(i * width, j * height);
      final color = Color.fromARGB(cell[3], cell[0], cell[1], cell[2]);
      map.putIfAbsent(color, () => HashSet()).add(offset);
    }
  }

  for (var e in map.entries) {
    canvas.drawPoints(
      PointMode.points,
      e.value.toList(),
      paint
        ..color = e.key
        ..blendMode = BlendMode.srcOver
        ..strokeWidth = 2.0,
    );
  }
}
```

Now the creation of map should be much faster. I did some benchmarking on my own and found out accessing 3d list with i and j takes more time than having a reference to it. Also, changed rowpoints to points. You could change it back.

Comment: This is a good improvement. With 40000 points the painting part takes 1-2 ms but the creation of the points takes 10-20 ms. Yeah I have to structure the code in away that I can save the map values so that I do not have to recreate them always

Comment: @MaLa please try updated answer. Alternatively, you can use iterator.